# Determining the size of the Operand Stack for a Stack Frame

Tags: compiler-construction, jvm

I am currently building a simple Virtual Machine as a side project with the end goal of implementing my own programming language from scratch. Anyway, I am trying to loosely copy many techniques seen in the JVM.

I noticed that when a function is called in the JVM, a stack frame is pushed onto the call stack containing three sections... the local variable array, the operand stack, and the frame data. My question is how does the JVM know how much space to allocate for the operand stack section. Is there a simple rule for determining how large the operand stack for a given function call should be?

Lastly, what happens if the operand stack fills up? Should the stack frame expand itself to compensate? Or should an error be thrown?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> how does the JVM know how much space to allocate for the operand stack section

"The maximum depth of the operand stack of a frame is determined at compile-time and is supplied along with the code for the method associated with the frame." JVMS [§2.6.2](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jvms/se15/html/jvms-2.html#jvms-2.6.2), [§4.7.3](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jvms/se15/html/jvms-4.html#jvms-4.7.3).

> what happens if the operand stack fills up?

As cited above, the size of the operand stack for each individual frame is known beforehand. The computation cannot use more operand stack than specified in the class file for a particular method, otherwise class verification would fail.

"At no point during execution can the operand stack grow to a depth greater than that implied by the max_stack item." JVMS [§4.9.2](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jvms/se15/html/jvms-4.html#jvms-4.9.2).

Comment: §2.5.2 is talking about the call stack (a.k.a. the Java Virtual Machine stack), not the operand stack. The only way that the operand stack could overflow would be if the maximum depth of the operand stack is incorrect, which would mean the bytecode is illegal and will be rejected during the verification stage.

Comment: @sepp2k Java Virtual Machine stack stores frames (§2.6), and the operand stack is a part of the frame (§2.6.2). Although the size of the operand stack of each individual frame is known beforehand (as I cited above), the specification explicitly permits Java Virtual Machine stacks to dynamically expand and contract as required by the computation. In particular, this means JVM *may* throw StackOverflowError when pushing to the operand stack. HotSpot JVM, however, performs [stack overflow check](https://pangin.pro/posts/stack-overflow-handling) on method entry.

Comment: §2.5.2 does not require throwing StackOverflowError or OutOfMemoryError only when pushing a new frame. But well, I removed the paragraph to avoid possible misinterpretation.

Comment: I appreciate the level of detail you guys are going into over a possible operand stack overflow. However, I am most interested in how the size of the operand stack is calculated. I now understand that this is the job of the compiler, not the jvm. Could y'all provide a quick example of how the compiler does this?... or maybe provide a link to an example/resource?

Comment: @c.abate Keep track of the stack depth while generating code for a method: Every time you emit an instruction that grows the stack, you increase the stack depth. Every time you emit an instruction that shrinks the stack, you decrease the stack depth. Every time the current depth of stack exceeds the maximum, you set the maximum to the current depth.

Comment: @sepp2k Thank you!!! I was going to ask about a situation where you have a `push` instruction inside of a loop... but I'm guessing a good compiler would never let this happen without a `pop` instruction also being in the loop.

Comment: @c.abate Exactly. When writing a verifier, you'll need to make sure that such a thing can't happen (i.e. that all incoming edges of a basic block come from blocks with the same outgoing stack depth), but when counting the depth in the code generator, you simply know that (barring bugs) this can't happen because you won't generate code that does that.

Comment: @c.abate in case of Java bytecode, you must even track the types that are expected to be on the operand stack, to provide stack map frames for branch merge points. This implies that the same type of items must be at the beginning of the loop as in the next iteration, otherwise, they are unusable. But usually, when you have modelled the elements of your programming language and converted the source code to a tree, this knowledge comes for free.